# Matrix of a linear transformation of tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose I have a linear transformation $T: V \to V'$. How can I easily obtain the matrix of the linear transformation from $V^{\otimes n}$ to $V'^{\otimes n}$ induced by $T$? What if I have transformations $T_i : V_i \to V'_i$? I can't seem to Google the right thing.

-- EDIT --

I know $T$ explicitly, i.e. I have a matrix for it (after fixing a basis, of course).

Comment: You want to look for "Kronecker Product" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: Note: the induced map is sometimes written as $T^{\otimes n}$, or $\otimes ^n T$